# How can I calculate the latitude and longitude of each pixel of an image in a kml file using Python?

Tags: python, geospatial, kml, latitude-longitude

I am using .kml file which points to an overlay image (presumably in UTM projection?). 
The KML file provides the latitudes and longitudes of the bounding box using the "LatLonBox" tag.

I need to calculate the latitudes and longitudes of each pixel in this image.

Are there any pre-existing libraries in Python that would do this for me?

Comment: CORRECTION: the overlay image is not in UTM projection but in geographic projection (Cylindrical Equidistant). This makes the solution very simple (see my answer below). I had been getting confused with Google Maps which uses UTM projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overlay image referenced by the kml file was in standard geographic projection.
This means that the latitudes and longitudes vary linearly within the image.

Calculating the latitude and longitude of each pixel became a trivial case of interpolation given that we already known the lat/lon bounds of the image provided by the LatLonBox tag attributes.